# Overlay pattern image on exact portion of png image with Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv3.0

I don't know the exact image processing terms to use here. However, what I wanted is the the design patter of one image in .jpg to be supper imposed on exact portion outline of a second image in .png.

```
from PIL import Image
design = Image.open("design.jpg")
mask = Image.open("mask.png")

design.paste(mask, (0, 0), mask)
design.save('result.png')
```

Using the above, I got this result:....[image]
As seen, the pattern covers the whole image, I just need it to cover the portion where there is information not the whole background.

The expect result is....
[image]

The input files are:-
[image]

[image]